# ionic side menu (official tutorial) give error

Tags: android, html, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I tried to follow their first tutorial here :

```
http://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/starting.html
```

However it returns a blank page, both in real device and browser emulator (ionic serve).

This is the error :

```
Error: [$compile:ctreq] Controller 'ionSideMenus', required by directive 'ionSideMenuContent', can't be found!
```

The code itself is very straight forward. I download a blank template (i just followed the official tutorial), and add this `html` code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title>Todo</title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="todo">

    <!--center-->
    <!-- <ion-pane>
      <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
        <h1 class="title">Ionic Blank Starter</h1>
      </ion-header-bar>
      <ion-content>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-pane> -->
    <ion-side-menu-content>
      <ion-header-bar class="bar-dark">
        <h1 class="title">Todo</h1>
      </ion-header-bar>
      <ion-content>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-side-menu-content>
    asd
    <!--nav bar-->
    <ion-side-menus>
      <ion-side-menu-content>
      </ion-side-menu-content>
      <ion-side-menu side="left">
      </ion-side-menu>
    </ion-side-menus>
  </body>
</html>
```

And this is my `app.js` :

```
angular.module('todo', ['ionic'])
.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})
```

What should i do to make the side project working?

Thanks a lot for your help

**UPDATE**

Thanks to **ThomasP1988**, now the error is gone. However, the white screen persists. I can see the content of my web for a split second (a blink of eye) before it turns to white, blank space evertime i run the project

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you should wrap

```
<ion-side-menu-content>
  <ion-header-bar class="bar-dark">
    <h1 class="title">Todo</h1>
  </ion-header-bar>
  <ion-content>
  </ion-content>
</ion-side-menu-content>
```

in `<ion-side-menus></ion-side-menus>`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help :) Please kindly see my other question if  you have time : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33594733/display-html-content-in-ion-nav-view