# Display html content in <ion-nav-view>

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I used to have `<div ng-view></div>` before i use `ionic`. I will use that `div` as a wrapper to contain any `html` i want.

I tried to do the same thing with `ionic`. This is my `index.html` :

```
<ion-pane>
  <ion-content>
    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-content>
</ion-pane>
```

And this is my `ionic router` :

```
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state('main', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'views/main.html'
    })

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/jobs')
})
```

However its not loading the `views/main.html`.

I tried to use `text/ng-template` in my `views/main.html`, so it looks like this :

```
<div>
    <ion-view>
        <p></p>
    </ion-view>
</div>
```

But its still not loading. There is no error or warning in the console.

Please kindly help me. Thanks for your help.

**UPDATE**

If i use wrong html path in templateUrl, the console shows error :

```
GET http://localhost:8100/views/main2.html 404 (Not Found)
```

However when i use the correct path, the cotent (only a

) is not displayed.

Comment: So, you are pointing your default url to /jobs which is not configured. Plus if its possible can you share your folder structure for view??

Comment: @AlexRumba Thanks a lot :) Thats certainly one of the culprit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 2 solutions for your template, and I think you mixed the two solutions

1. you can wrap it in `<script type="text/ng-template" id="main.html"></script>` but you will have to in clude your page manualy `<script src=""></script>` .If you use this solution, you don't have to write the path in routing `templateUrl: 'views/main.html'` the id is enough `templateUrl: 'main.html'`
2. Simply put your unwrapped content `<ion-view><!--content--></ion-view>` in a html file and write the correct path in templateUrl

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me again. I decided to use the 2nd solution. Please kindly see my updated code in the question. The content is not displayed yet

Comment: put <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view> in your index and <ion-view>
    <ion-content class="padding"><!--content--></ion-content>
</ion-view> in main.html

Comment: Thanks a lot :) I found the culprit : `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/jobs')`, i have no `jobs` defined. Please kindly help me again if you have time : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33610179/ionic-href-inside-ion-item-not-working-in-android-real-device