# ionic href inside ion-item not working in android real device

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I have a `<ion-item>` with `<a>` inside it. I want the apps go to specific `href` when the `<ion-item>` is clicked.

The code is working perfectly in browser emulator (`ionic serve`), but it cant be clicked on the android real device.

This is my `<ion-item>` :

```
        <ion-item>
            <a href="http://google.com">
                <img src="img/ionic.png">
                <p>Events</p>
            </a>
        </ion-item>
```

Note that the above `href` goes to external html.

The `href` is working if i try to go to local `html` :

```
        <ion-item>
            <a href="#/jobs">
                <img src="img/ionic.png">
                <p>Jobs List</p>
            </a>
        </ion-item>
```

I have tried change `href` to `ng-href`, i also tried specify the `href` inside the `ion-item` tag. None of them is working.

I also tried to change the order of the `html` :

```
<a href="http://google.com">
    <ion-item>
            <img src="img/ionic.png">
            <p>Forum</p>
    </ion-item>
</a>
```

Its still not working.

Please kindly help me, Thanks for your help

UPDATE

I also tried to use `inappbrowser` :

```
        <ion-item>
            <a href="#" 
            onclick="window.open('http://google.com', '_system', 'location=yes'); return false;">
                <img src="img/ionic.png">
                <p>Guide</p>
            </a>
        </ion-item>
```

But no luck on the real device

Comment: you shouldn't use onclick() with angular, use the ng-click instead and make a function in your controller, don't forget to include $window service

Comment: If you could actually post your error that you see in the console(try ionic run android -l -c), it would have been easier. Inappbrowser must have worked, Neway if you want a work around try using normal javascript as in :
https://blog.nraboy.com/2014/12/open-dynamic-links-using-cordova-inappbrowser/

Answer (score 1):

you can install in-app browser plugin in your cordova http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/inAppBrowser/

or if you don't want, just use $window.open('http://google.com', '_system'); in your controller

source : http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/linking-to-an-external-url-and-opening-in-browser/30953

Comment: Thanks again for helping me :) I have tried to use `inappbrowser`, please see my updated question